# Setting page on UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using the Xcode 6.1's PageViewController template.  I have a button in my app that is supposed to take the user back to the first page, but I'm unsure how to get this working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `UIPageViewController`'s `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` method.  The awkward bit is how to get your button to trigger that method.  I assume you have a main view controller, that creates VCs for each of the pages, creates and presents the UIPageViewController, and acts as its dataSource, providing the correct VC in the `viewControllersBefore...` and `viewControllersAfter...` methods.  The route I would follow is as follows:

1. In the VCs for the pages (or at least the one with the button), declare a protocol with one method (let's call it `returnToFirstPage`) which will be used to trigger the return to first page.

   ```
   @protocol PageSelection
   -(void)returnToFirstPage;
   @end
   ```
2. Also declare a property called `delegate` which implements this protocol

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) id <PageSelection> delegate;
   ```
3. Give the button a target/action to a method which then calls the delegate method:

   ```
   -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIBUtton *)sender {
       [self.delegate returnToFirstPage];
   }
   ```
4. In your main view controller, after creating the instances of the page view controllers, set the delegate to self.

   ```
   page1ViewController.delegate = self; // etc etc for other pages
   ```
5. In your main view controller, implement the delegate method, to handle the page change:

   ```
   -(void)returnToFirstPage {
       [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[page1ViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerDirectionBackward animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
   ```

I assume that you are only showing one page at a time.  Apologies if you're using Swift, but I hope you get the gist.